# KiCad ERC (electrical rules checker) error. Why?

Tags: pcb-design, usb, kicad

I recently got into PCB design with KiCad and am a beginner. I am trying to make a portable phone charger, but for some reason keep getting this error:

[image: Electrical Rules Checker error message]

I'm assuming it is caused by the fact that I'm improperly using the two USB ports in order to charge/use as a portable device, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the schematic for reference:

[image: Schematic]

Here are also the datasheets for the protection IC and charger:

Charger: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001984g.pdf

Protection IC: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP9101C.pdf

Comment: You are not permitted to use an edit to entirely change the nature of the question being asked, *especially* not after the original question has received an answer.  Your improper edit has been rolled back.  Additionally, the sort of broad open-ended design review question you were trying to turn this into is not really a fit for this site.

Comment: I guess I'm in the wrong place then. I will figure it out myself.

Answer (score 5):

J1 pin 5 is Ground.  U4 pin 6 is Vbat which connects to P+ in the bottom right drawing.  However, the bottom left drawing shows P+ connected to Ground, which is probably not right.

I'm a bit surprised that you didn't get a complaint about one net having two names: Vbat and P+ in the bottom right drawing.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but that does make sense. These are the data sheets that I got the applicational example from: Protection IC: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP9101C.pdf Charger:http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001984g.pdf

Comment: The typical application for the APC9101C shows a battery between P+ and Ground - your circuit shows a short circuit.  When you fix that, you'll probably get a complaint about two names on the same net - Vbat and P+ - most CAD programs won't accept that.

Comment: I added a battery and surprisingly there was no complaint about two names on the same netlist. However, what would be considered a good value for the battery that I'm using?

Comment: KiCAD allows to put multiple labels to the same net. The net ID is safed/handled separately.

Comment: @ChristianB.: Thanks - I used Altium at work, which didn't allow multiple names on a net.  From force of habit, I haven't tried multiple names in my limited use of KiCAD.

Comment: Wouldn't placing a battery in the schematic defeat the whole purpose of the lithium-ion battery though?

Comment: @dreece2498 The APC9101 is a battery protection IC, so it makes sense to show the battery it is protecting on the schematic.  You could show a connector marked "To Battery", if you insist, but a short circuit instead of the battery is definitely wrong.

Comment: @dreece2498: You do show two connection points apparently going to a battery, but that is not where the data sheet shows the battery.

Comment: Is there a way to place a picture in the comments? I changed it to how the schematic has it but I want to make sure it's correct.

Comment: @dreece2498: you can edit your original question to add another schematic or other information.  There should be an "Edit" button below your question, I think.

Comment: @dreece2498: PLEASE read and follow the APC9101 datasheet.  Your updated schematic shows the battery terminals in the right place, but they are shorted. Power to the APC9101 circuit should go the left end of R5, not directly to the APC9101.

Comment: Got it, sorry for the mix-up. Still kinda new with this whole thing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

The warnings in kicad are there to get you as a designer to check on them. It does not mean its wrong. Just usually that would be an issue with no other context.

In this situation if you know that this is not an issue for you. Then you can ignore it. Later development builds of kicad even let you hide errors you know are not an issue.

E.g. having a tristate microcontroller pin connected to an output would flag an error. But if I know that pin will only ever be an input as a designer. I can either ignore the error or change the pin definition to suit my specific use case.

The rule checking in the pcb layout is more clear cut. And generally those should not be ignored.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you are saying. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you know the pin will only ever be an input, then as the designer you should mark it as such on your schematic, and failing to do so means your schematic is incorrect and will convey inaccurate information to anyone who reads it.  This includes yourself.  Being the designer doesn't make you immune to lapses in memory or other mistakes.  The example you give is not in any way caused by lack of context, it is an example of KiCad correctly giving an error because your schematic is incorrect.  There is no missing context here, only an inappropriately designated pin function.

Comment: I completely understand the schematic is easily one of the most crucial parts of the PCB board. I've only been using this program for like 3 weeks and I know I'm probably making some pretty stupid mistakes, but that's how you learn.

Comment: Metacollin. Kicad as software has no context if that is a valid circuit, just that power output to power output = display warning. E.g 2 power OR controllers with the outputs tied would flag the same error. But in that case would be a valid circuit. Its still up to the designer to make sure that warning is not a problem.